# dyld: Library not loaded: iOS app crash Xcode 11.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have added ObjectMapper library using CocoaPods. Here is my Pod file:

```
target 'Example' do

  use_frameworks!

  pod 'ObjectMapper'

end
```

when I run the app it crashes resulting the following error

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/ObjectMapper.framework/ObjectMapper
Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7DC2B7C8-C3B8-4250-B4D3-6E373C20DB8E/Example.app/Example
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7DC2B7C8-C3B8-4250-B4D3-6E373C20DB8E/Example.app/Frameworks/ObjectMapper.framework/ObjectMapper: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7DC2B7C8-C3B8-4250-B4D3-6E373C20DB8E/Example.app/Frameworks/ObjectMapper.framework/ObjectMapper'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7DC2B7C8-C3B8-4250-B4D3-6E373C20DB8E/Example.app/Frameworks/ObjectMapper.framework/ObjectMapper: stat() failed with errno=25
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7DC2B7C8-C3B8-4250-B4D3-6E373C20DB8E/Example.app/Frameworks/ObjectMapper.framework/ObjectMapper: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7DC2B7C8-C3B8-4250-B4D3-6E373C20DB8E/Example.app/Frameworks/ObjectMapper.framework/ObjectMapper'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7DC2B7C8-C3B8-4250-B4D3-6E373C20DB8E/Example.app/Frameworks/ObjectMapper.framework/ObjectMapper: stat() failed with errno=1
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7DC2B7C8-C3B8-4250-B4D3-6E373C20DB8E/Example.app/Frameworks/ObjectMapper.framework/ObjectMapper: code signature invalid for '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7DC2B7C8-C3B8-4250-B4D3-6E373C20DB8E/Example.app/Frameworks/ObjectMapper.framework/ObjectMapper'

/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/7DC2B7C8-C3B8-4250-B4D3-6E373C20DB8E/Example.app/Frameworks/ObjectMapper.framework/ObjectMapper: stat() failed with errno=1
```

I've tried all the solutions proposed in similar questions asked here earlier but nothing seems to be working.

then I removed "use_frameworks!" line from the pod file and the crash issue was gone.

How do I resolve the crash issue while having "use_frameworks!" in the pod file?

Comment: Have you added the platform version on the Podfile?

Comment: Can help: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3586

Answer (score 0):

Please add your Pods_project_name.framework in **Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content**

Tap on + button and select your Pods_project_name.framework

Comment: doing that triggers a build error "multiple commands produce...". however, in Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries, changing the status from 'Required' to 'Optional' gets rid of the error and the crash is gone as well. although I'm not sure if that's the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I always solve these issues with CocoaPods by trying

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

This rebuilds the entire cocoapods project